# WP_Debug does not work even wp-config and .htacess modified

Tags: php, wordpress, debugging

i am trying to troubleshoot about my wordpress. When i migrate my wordpress to another domain or localhost, debugging works fine. Thats probably about some core files i’ve made changes or some plugin did. When i migrate website i don’t deactivate any plugins but debugging still works. Here is the command lists what i added to wp-config.php but did not get any response.

```
defined( 'WP_DEBUG' ) or defined( 'WP_DEBUG', TRUE );
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

writing these codes above “Happy blogging bla bla..” line.
Tried to deactivate all plugins, did not work.
Tried to call wp_debug_mode() by manual, website got down.

it also does not create a error-log file. it creates on migrated wordpress but not in original wordpress. definetly i should change something but can not find what.

What else i can try to fix it? I also added these ones to .htaccess file

```
php_flag display_startup_errors on
php_flag display_errors on
php_flag html_errors on
php_flag  log_errors on
php_value error_log  /home/mywebsitedomainhide.com/PHP_errors.log
```

still not responding. i am out of solutions, anyone?

Comment: You must be rushing because `.htaccess` has two c's. And if you are rushing then you may be overlooking things. Slow down.

Comment: @mardubbles yes i am kinda rushing because i have a deadline and still not able to see errors. first have to see them, then i can solve them. thank you for advice may be i can take a break but i hope someone can give me a hand about this

Comment: Could be the hosting provider. You don't mention the environment when *things dont work* in your question. You only mention when it did work.

Comment: *What else i can try to fix it?* Could be wherever you are deploying this to, has some form of q&a on common answers. I could glance over it for you but you didn't provide what service you are using?

Comment: In possibly like parallel, I was dealing with this one hosting provider that had a completely different implementation of `mail()` so it ended up with a helpful discussion on their tech people. Could be that this could be similar where different implementations are used that vary from your dev environment.

Comment: Is it cpanel hosting?

Comment: @mardubbles i am using AWS but not using any kind of panel because provider does not offer it. I know its old fashion but using ftp.  Should i contact with my provider?

Comment: @HowardE no, unfortunately it is not

Comment: @mardubbles also it was working until 2 months ago, since i did not change many things but probably changed something then. but it can be only in wp files, not at hostsing side because i dont have panel. may be should contact with provider